# Cannot override sass variables

Tags: webpack, vue.js, sass, sass-loader

I am using library 'keen-ui' in my project. That lib uses sass, to define styles. I want to override this styles. I connected sass loader to my project and it works fine, but problem is that sass loader loads my file 'variables.scss' before standard 'variables.scss' of keen-ui, so it does not override variables. Can someone suggest a way to load my custom 'variables.scss' after standard?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can import your dependencies directly from your .scss main file, and choose by yourself the order. For instance:

```
@import '.node_modules/Keen-UI/src/styles/utils;
@import 'my-variables';
@import '.node_modules/Keen-UI/src/styles/variables;
@import '.node_modules/Keen-UI/src/styles/mixins;
@import '.node_modules/Keen-UI/src/styles/components;
```

I used to import Bootstrap this way, so I could have some control on the framework components and be sure to only import the components I actually use.

But your issue might be something else since it appears that the variables from Keen-UI all have a `!default` flag, meaning that the reference is only used if there is no similar reference before or after...

https://github.com/JosephusPaye/Keen-UI/blob/next/src/styles/variables.scss